# SSL connect types

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jetty

One way of creating SSL server is by issuing Keystore and Password. Is there any other way to create SSL Sever in any Web servers without Keystore/Password something like that? If I want my server to be secured, I must issue Keystore and Password right? or any other way to achieve this?

and What is Certificate in SSL, what is the different between Certificate and Keystore file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One way of creating SSL server is by issuing Keystore and Password.

Correct.

> Is there any other way to create SSL Sever in any Web servers without Keystore/Password

No. There are various ways of soecifying the keystore and the password, but you need to use one of them.

> If I want my server to be secured, I must issue Keystore and Password right?

Yes.

> or any other way to achieve this?

For all practical purposes for someone of your level of expertise, no.

> what is the different between Certificate and Keystore file.

A keystore file holds certificates and private keys.

Comment: Since you mentioned tomcat and jetty in your tags, know that both of them have to use the java built-ins for SSL, which require keystore / truststore, which in turn requires passwords to be provided (even if the keystore is built without a password, it still needs to be declared and passed in as empty)